# Pass Image to another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, image

This might looks like another questions about passing data that have been already replied, but not (I have searched many times in stackoverflow)

I explain :

I use Firebase to authentificate users.
In my problem, I use Google Sign In, and the func is located in **Appdelegate**

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
```

I have a navigation based on scrollView (https://github.com/jakespracher/Snapchat-Swipe-View) so the viewdidload/didappear is launched only once on my app (at the beginning, and not when I swipe to the UIController).

So my question:

I want to pass an image from my func sign (the Google Profile Image) from my **Appdelegate**, to a **ProfileViewController**.
I want to do it from my func in my **Appdelegate** (the segue/present doesn't work. present because it's on appdelegate and segue because the viewdidload/did appear only launch once)

So how can I do ?

I tried this on my func sign on **Appdelegate**, but it goes nowhere with a nil on  *controller.profile.image* :

```
let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data)!
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Profile") as! ProfileViewController

controller.profile.image = image
```

So please please please, I will be grateful if somebody helps me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are going in wrong way, you are trying to set image to an ImageView of a ViewController which is not Loaded yet.

you can take and UIImage object in you view controller  and On ViewDidLoad you can set the image to your ImageView.

```
class ProfileViewController : UIViewController {
var imageFromPreviousPage : UIImage?

@IBOutlet weak var profile: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    profile.image = imageFromPreviousPage
}
}
```

Now set your image to this image object

```
let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data)!
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Profile") as! ProfileViewController
controller. imageFromPreviousPage = image
```

Now you can push your navigation controller to above ViewController.

If you are trying it from Appdelegate didFinishLauch you need to set it as the root view of your window .

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I'll try that ! Thanks for the post!